Sci-fi trilogy involving a noble family who buy a girl from a race of subservient beings to bond with their girl
There was like a subservient race of beings who would bond with one person and this noble family bought one for their girl. Learning was banned but the noble family were caught supporting it or something. They were told to send their girl to court where she would probably be executed, but instead they send the subservient girl to pretend to be the noble one. At the court, the girl meets the mad nephew of the ruler who isn’t actually mad but he was pretending so his uncle wouldn’t now try to have him killed. They also worship this guy, I think, who they believe to be immortal but he only lives so long because he lives in or beside a black hole.It might not have been a trilogy and i think the noble girls name began with a p

I'm guessing this is a trilogy of books, but can you confirm that? Also, in roughly which year did you read this? And which character is the protagonist in this story?

I think this is The Diabolic Series by SJ Kincaid. It fits the description and a lot of the details match up.

Nemesis is a Diabolic, created to protect Sidonia, the daughter of a galactic senator. There’s no one Nemesis wouldn’t kill to keep her safe. So when the power-mad Emperor summons Sidonia to the Galactic court to serve as a hostage, Nemesis takes her place.
The court is a nest of vipers that Nemesis struggles to navigate without revealing her true abilities. As the Empire begins to fracture and rebellion looms closer, Nemesis finds a humanity within herself that may just be the thing that saves her.
In the ensuing fight for power and for peace, Nemesis must decide what lines she’s not willing to cross, recover from devastating betrayals, and put everything on the line to protect the people she loves.


Thanks I think it was the diabolic series

This looks like a great story!  I may just have to get hold of it and check it out...
